# Migrating bareos storage to another

Tags: linux, backup, migration, copy

We have a host A with bareos SD  and the storage "backups". We want to migrate the data from host A to another storage (host B) temporarily.
We have to reinstall the host A for performance reasons.

When reinstalling, new copy host B data to host A.

For this, we have implemented several copy jobs (http://doc.bareos.org/master/html/bareos-manual-main-reference.html#x1-23900021) with the "selection-type" "PoolUncopiedJobs" to copy the data of the machine A to machine B.

I tested a data restoration from machine B => OK.

My questions :

Is it possible to rebuild the catalog from Host B data and then initiate backup jobs with the storage B.

Is this scenario possible? Rsync would it not be easier in this context?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a temporary operation, copying the whole backup dir to another SD host can be easier and quickier than managing duplicates directly in Bareos. The only thing you need to remember to preserve existing backups (both data and catalog) is **never change volume names**. I would also be careful changing SD instance name (`Name = ...`), it's safer to only edit the IP/hostname (which is not referenced in catalog database AFAIK).

An interesting solution to avoid long downtime of SD host (during volume files migration from A to B) is to run a network replication (ie. DRBD) on top of existing backup directory block device. Look at [this thread](http://lists.linbit.com/pipermail/drbd-user/2010-July/014404.html) for explanation of the idea. This allows for quick switching of the hosts both times.